# Better Version Control than TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I am working on TFS for Version Controlling since one year. It was good with Visual Studio but some days ago my PC Crashed and the Code on my local Machine Which were not Checked in Destroy... Then I have worked again which took much time and my project got late. Now I decide to move from TFS to another better Version controlling then TFS which handle code locally as well as on the server. 
please advise me if anyone use good version control tool for Visual Studio. Thanks in advance

Comment: TFS is not a version control system.  TFS supports version control (Git and TFVC) along with its other capabilities like agile project management and CI/CD.  TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) is the name of the centralized version control system component of TFS.

Comment: Yes, I am using TFVC . is there any other VC that is good then TFVC ?

Comment: What version control system would have prevented you from **not having committed code to version control**?

Comment: Thank All for Suggestion. now I decide to move to GIT which is much convenient then TFVC for my issue. I will refer GIT to all who are confused for selecting GIT or TFVC.

Answer (score 2):

Just like *Edward* commented TFS is not a version control system. Which is a  product that provides source code management (either with Team Foundation Version Control or Git), reporting, requirements management, project management, automated builds, lab management, testing and release management capabilities. It **covers the entire application lifecycle**, and enables DevOps capabilities.

TFS supports two types of version control: Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). One centralized and one distributed. As for which version control system should you use, you could take a look at this thread: **[Choosing the right version control for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc)**

For your case, you should be checking in **frequently** or setup some sort of **backup system** to avoid mistakes like this. Or set an alarm clock, memos to remind you to commit code to version control. If the files are gone from your file system, they're gone.

Comment: Or use Visual Studio Team Services to have the same version control features hosted for you in the cloud. This means you don't need to worry about the backups. https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/

Comment: Thank All for Suggestion. now I decide to move to GIT which is much convenient then TFVC for my issue. I will refer GIT to all who are confused for selecting GIT or TFVC